# Issue mBot and 2.4G WiFi dongle. No upload possible

Tags: arduino

Have an issue with mBot and 2.4G dongle. 
Device is mBot V1.1 WiFI 2.4G.
Using original SW mBlock v3.4.11
Having operating system Windows 10
I can control mBot via Wireless dongle by keyboard, but cannot upload code. I get error:

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "HID": The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

I do not know what to do. I am not a programmer.
Please help me to enable it for my son.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the latest version of mBlock:

https://mblock.makeblock.com/en-us/download/

However, if you do not wish to download it, you can use the mBlock web IDE:

https://ide.mblock.cc/

Make sure that you are connecting to the right port, too. If you are connecting to a port named “Com1”, you are most likely connecting to the wrong port.
Also, be sure to ask your question on the official mBlock Forum:

https://forum.makeblock.com/

I've found a similar topic on there here:

https://forum.makeblock.com/t/code-not-uploading-to-my-mbot-ranger/20879/

Thanks for your time,
Best Codes